# Doing the opposite of baking normals

Tags: modeling, normals

I am trying to model a helmet from Doom Eternal, and I have a model from the game as well as textures and Normal maps. My ultimate goal is to 3D print, so I need the detail in the mesh itself. What I want to do is change the vertices of the model I have using the normal map so I can have higher detail. I want to avoid starting from scratch by using the things I already have.

Comment: You said you have textures and normal maps, do those textures include height maps? If not, you will have to find some way to convert the Normal Map to a Height Map (maybe use AwesomeBump?), and then use the height map as a basis for displacement.

Comment: Yeah what Bennett said. You can subdivide your model by a lot, then add a displacement modifier. Set coordinates to UV and add your texture to it.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Displace modifier can use Normals too ... So why convert to Bump? Did I miss something? Thank you

Comment: Normal maps store information about surface angles, but no depth information. Blender lacks the ability to properly "assume" height information from a normal map because it's shader system is evaluated in such a way that each pixel is "unaware" of the state of the adjacent pixels (or any other in the texture map for that matter), and therefore cannot calculate to what extent an angled edge, for example, represents a height difference between two different flat sections. Thus, displacement from a Normal map will always be lacking compared to displacement from a true height map.

Comment: Ha ... sorry ... right ... I was sitting on my brain :)

Comment: The edges created by the displacement modifier are all very blunt. Is there any way I can sharpen them up?

Comment: Increase the number of subdivisions, maybe?

Comment: I'm already at 6 subdivisions and Blender crashes if I try and go any further